# phusion passenger processes dying and new ones starting up mysteriously

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby-on-rails-3

as you can see, passenger processes are dying and new ones booting up, even though we're not explicitly restarting passenger ourselves. we can't pinpoint what's causing this. what are some common places we should look to find out what's triggering these restarts?

the `passenger-status` commands were issued about 30 min apart. `passenger_pool_idle_time` is set to 0 in our conf file, which you can see here: https://gist.github.com/panabee/8ddf95a72d6a07e29c7f

we're on passenger 4.0.5, rails 3.2.12, and nginx 1.4.1.

```
[root@mongo ~]# passenger-status
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 20
Processes     : 3
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/p/p#default:
  App root: /home/p/p
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 17171   Sessions: 0       Processed: 536     Uptime: 27m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 62M     Last used: 20s ago
  * PID: 18087   Sessions: 0       Processed: 363     Uptime: 17m 31s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 36M     Last used: 39s ago
  * PID: 19382   Sessions: 0       Processed: 51      Uptime: 2m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 34M     Last used: 5s ago

[root@mongo ~]# passenger-status
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 20
Processes     : 2
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/p/p#default:
  App root: /home/p/p
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 25266   Sessions: 0       Processed: 73      Uptime: 2m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 32M     Last used: 34s ago
  * PID: 25462   Sessions: 1       Processed: 18      Uptime: 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 28M     Last used: 0s ago

[root@mongo ~]#
```

config.ru:

```
[root@newvps Tekiki]# cat config.ru
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Tekiki::Application
```

Comment: Could you please post your application's config.ru file?

Comment: done, @fsoppelsa. any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in 4.0.5, will get fixed in 4.0.6. In the meantime, set pool_idle_time to a large value.

Comment: Is this bug documented? Could you please provide a URL?

Comment: we emailed the makers of passenger, not sure if they posted publicly.